# What is the ATC protocol for hijackings?

Tags: air-traffic-control, commercial-aviation, radio-communications, hijack

If a commercial aircraft is successfully hijacked, by a competent pilot / pilots, and they make contact with ATC for regular requests (i.e. weather updates, flight path information or clearing air traffic), will ATC still aid the (new) pilots, or do they have some other procedure, like trying to persuade them to hand control back to the original pilots?

I'm just wondering if there is a formal procedure for such an event, as I'm guessing it's rather unlikely that they would contact ATC like that. But always possible, of course.

Comment: I'm sure there are protocols for who they notify, but procedures will vary widely between countries. As for giving assistance, if the hijackers intend to land the airplane it's in the interests of everyone that ATC helps them. Knowing the intentions would be tricky of course.

Comment: Example: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/feb/17/copilot-arrested-hijacking-ethiopian-plane

Comment: @Ben Very interesting but I wonder if he actually spoke to ATC to land? Or just went for an empty runway...

Comment: @Pondlife Will they release it if someone emails them? Or maybe someone working for FAA on this site can obtain the procedures...

Comment: @Cloud I have no idea, but I think it's very unlikely. Why would the government share (presumably) classified security protocols with anyone who just asks?

Comment: @Pondlife Hmm... ok, I'll give it 24 hours and if nothing, maybe close the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Cloud They're not publicly available. We are the public. Therefore, they are not available to us.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sure, but the question actually had a suitable accepted answer, not sure I see the benefit in closing the question after the fact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the US, the ATC protocol for hijackings is classified for reasons of national security.

> #### 10-2-6 Hijacked aircraft
>
> Hijack attempts or actual events are a matter of
>   national security and require special handling. Policy
>   and procedures for hijack situations are detailed in
>   *FAAO JO 7610.4, Special Operations*.<sup>‡</sup> FAAO
>   JO 7610.4 describes reporting requirements, air crew
>   procedures, air traffic procedures and escort or
>   interceptor procedures for hijack situations

[*Air Traffic Organization Policy*, FAA, 2015-12-10](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/ATC.pdf).

<sup>‡</sup>[This document's content can only be accessed from within the FAA network.](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1031968)

Comment: I thought maybe some ATCs would be active on this site that could reveal the info... thanks though :)

Comment: As valuable as internet points are, not sure they’re worth risking your job, country, and freedom for.

Answer (score 3):

According to ICAO doc 4444 ATC will treat the hijacked aircraft with extra care - since the aircraft is considered to be in a state of emergency. Extra separation will be provided between the hijacked aircraft and other aircraft.

> 15.1.3.3 Whenever unlawful interference with an aircraft is known or suspected or a bomb threat warning has been received, ATS units shall promptly attend to requests by, or to anticipated needs of, the aircraft, including requests for relevant information relating to air navigation facilities, procedures and services along the route of flight and at any aerodrome of intended landing, and shall take such action as is necessary to expedite the conduct of all phases of the flight.

This does not mean that the authorities will not take some other actions - but what they will do is classified.